# Azure VMSS 10 model limit?

Tags: azure, azure-vm-scale-set

Recently when I update my VMSS model, I received error like

> MyVmssName has reached its limit of 10 models that may be referenced
> by one or more VMs belonging to the Virtual Machine Scale Set. . Upgrade the VMs to the latest model of the Virtual Machine Scale Set before trying again.

Does Azure have some official documentation on this 10 model limitation? Could not find it anywhere.

Comment: @Imran the above quote is exactly the error I got in Azure Portal.

Answer (score 0):

**I have referred similar Issue:**

When a change is made to the **VMSS**, such as a cluster upgrade, the change must be applied to the existing instances.

If **VMSS** using the manual upgrade policy. This means that when a change is made, the user must manually update the old instances.

**Azure Portal > Impacted VMSS > Instances tab**.

The CX can then select each instance which is showing **Latest Model** as No and upgrade one by one. I would not recommend upgrading all instances at once as this may bring the **VMSS** down.

[image]

Also upgrade **VMSS** instances using **Azure CLI**.

[image]

if **VMSS** upgrade policy is set to automatic, instances will upgrade automatically in random order.

[image]

You can also upgrade VMSS using Azure CLI.

```
az vmss update --name <VMSSName> --resource-group <ResourceGroupname> --license-type windows_server
```

[image]

Reference: [Update VMSS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vmss?view=azure-cli-latest#az-vmss-update)